# Change the scope of code called within a ruby block

Tags: ruby, scope

Suppose I have a method that looks like:

```
def do_something (&code)
    code.call
end
```

Now I want to use this to set a variable in the outer scope.

```
do_something do
    foo = 'bar'
end
puts foo #=>undefined
```

This is obviously because foo is defined within the scope of the do_something method, how do I get it populate in the outer scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you not to use this approach. Basically you should not want to expand internal scope outside. Better practice here will be to return some state from your block.

```
def do_something (&code)
  code.call
end

foo = do_something do
  'bar'
end

p foo
#=> bar
```